# Swift 5 API call data variable nil but API proved working

Tags: ios, swift, api

I ran in some trouble while trying go get my iOS App talking to my express backend.

I'm just starting with swift and iOS development but in my opinion this should work:

```
func fetchLoc() {
    var currentLoc: CLLocation!
    
    currentLoc = locationManager.location
    
    let latitude = String(currentLoc.coordinate.latitude)
    let longitude = String(currentLoc.coordinate.longitude)
    
    //let url = URL(string: "a542cd3116ed.ngrok.io/api/v1/public/location/66.68994/10.249066/50")!
    let url = URL(string: "http://a542cd3116ed.ngrok.io/api/v1/public/" + "location/" + latitude + "/" + longitude + "/100")!

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
        do {
            if((data) != nil) {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
                print(json)
            }
        } catch {
            print("error")
        }
    })

    task.resume()
}
```

The problem is, Data is always nil. As you can see I already tried inserting the complete URL for testing. But it doesn't make any difference. It has to be a problem with my code because I can call the API from Insomnia just fine. The answer looks like this, so its proper JSON:

```
[
  {
    "location": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
        66.68994,
        10.249066
      ]
    },
    "type": "shop",
    "name": "Laden weg 60",
    "description": null,
    "status": "active",
    "taxRates": [
      0.19,
      0.07
    ],
    "currency": "EUR",
    "_id": "602e390b7c760032c0cc74d7",
    "address": {
      "street": "abc1",
      "number": null,
      "city": null,
      "zip": null,
      "country": "DE",
      "_id": "602e390b7c760032c0cc74d8"
    },
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

I hope I'm just overseeing something obvious here. Thank you in advance!

Postman generated this code:

```
import Foundation
#if canImport(FoundationNetworking)
import FoundationNetworking
#endif

var semaphore = DispatchSemaphore (value: 0)

var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://a542cd3116ed.ngrok.io/api/v1/public/location/66.68994/10.249066/50")!,timeoutInterval: Double.infinity)
request.httpMethod = "GET"

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in 
  guard let data = data else {
    print(String(describing: error))
    semaphore.signal()
    return
  }
  print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
  semaphore.signal()
}

task.resume()
semaphore.wait()
```

Comment: It just doesn't go in the if because data is always nil.

Comment: `print("error")` => `print("Error while deserializing: \(error)")`, it might be helpful later. BUT, start by printing `error` at top, in case of `data` being nil. Unrelated, but ` if((data) != nil) {` whould be `if let data = data { }`, soft unwrap.

Comment: Thank you for those tipps, but no luck so far. I looked at data in the debugger, it's definitely nil anyway.

Comment: Can you make it work with POSTMAN? I know that POSTMAN can generate Swift code (not Swifty code, but still working code), to see if it works at all. It might help spot the diff and the erro. https://blog.postman.com/use-your-work-in-postman-to-generate-code-for-your-apps/

Comment: Works no problem with Insomnia, but let me try Postman. Installing it right now.

Comment: I saw that Insomnia also can generate code: https://support.insomnia.rest/article/37-code-snippet-generation what's is it saying?

Comment: Just installed Postman. I don't know this command `DispatchSemaphore` but I'm looking it up now. Thank you for pointing me towards this CodeGen features. Didn't know about them.

Comment: No, don't worry about DispatchSemaphore() stuff. Just that if you use that generated code isntead of yours, does your request work?

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution Postman generated works for me:

```
import Foundation
#if canImport(FoundationNetworking)
import FoundationNetworking
#endif

var semaphore = DispatchSemaphore (value: 0)

var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://a542cd3116ed.ngrok.io/api/v1/public/location/66.68994/10.249066/50")!,timeoutInterval: Double.infinity)
request.httpMethod = "GET"

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in 
  guard let data = data else {
    print(String(describing: error))
    semaphore.signal()
    return
  }
  print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
  semaphore.signal()
}

task.resume()
semaphore.wait()
```

Comment: This is a hard-coded URL, have you ever validated the URL with the lat and lng variables?

Comment: It's not Swifty code, it's bad. Question now, is what's `url.absoluteSring` in your case not working? Is it correct?

Comment: Don't know exactly what you mean with url.absoluteString but I tried both, the hardcoded URL and the generated one.